# Don't send an e-mail while I'm looking at the website?

Tags: feature-request, email-notification

It would be nice if StackOverflow wouldn't send me e-mails about the new questions in my subscribed categories when I'm actually browsing the website, especially those particular sections.

Comment: I think this should be a per user setting.  Some users use their email as a record of questions in their tags.